# HTML5 JS fillRect() strange behavior

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm having two odd problems with fillrect(x, y, width, height).

1. Is multiplying the value of "height" by two
2. X and y is supposed to be set to the mouse position, but the rectangle is off to the bottom left, and gets further away as the mouse moves to the bottom left.

This code is from a video tutorial, and the code seems to work for the guy and the video, and everyone else since no one commented having the same problem. Anyways here is the code:

```
function doFirst(){
    canv = document.getElementById('canvas');
    canvas = canv.getContext('2d');

    document.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove, false);
}

function onMouseMove(e){
    canvas.clearRect(0, 0, canv.width, canv.height);
    var x = e.clientX;
    var y = e.clientY;
    canvas.fillRect(x, y, 50, 50);
}

window.addEventListener("load", doFirst, false);
```

I thought maybe I missed a step in the tutorial, and after checking over and over I decided to simplify it to just drawing a rectangle without the mouse listener, yet the canvas still drew it with 2X the height and about 2x the y position.

```
function doFirst(){
    canv = document.getElementById('canvas');
    canvas = canv.getContext('2d');

    canvas.fillRect(10, 10, 50, 50);
}

window.addEventListener("load", doFirst, false);
```

The fillRect function was working fine just the other day when I first started playing with HTML5 canvas, so what happened? how did I break it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe this happens because you're trying to set the width and height of the canvas with CSS:

```
<!--Sets size of the canvas on the page-->
<canvas id="canvas" style="width:500px; height:500px;"></canvas>
```

Instead, use this:

```
<!--Sets drawing surface size-->
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

The "width" and "height" attributes indicate the size of the drawing surface, which by default is 300x150. Setting the CSS width and height of the canvas will expand or shrink the drawing surface, but will not change the number of pixels in the surface. `fillRect` takes
coordinates in "drawing surface" pixels, not "HTML page pixels".